# TFS build error: Web deployment task failed. Package file does not have a .zip file name extension

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am getting the following error when I am queuing a build in TFS 2017.

"Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets 3009,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Package file 'C:\agent_work\3\s\TestApp\TestApp\release' does not have a .zip file name extension.)"

[image]

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I have hosted agent on the TFS server. I created the build definition according to this video:

www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjD4A-yeFTE

Does somebody have any idea? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you share the build logs and the detailed arguments in VSBuild task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test at my side and everything works correctly.
Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Please check the drop folder, if the .zip file actually being in the
  place that you expected.
- Try to specify the output path, eg:
  `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"` , then
  specify the **Copy Root** path as `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`
  in `Copy and Publish Build Artifacts` task.
- Explicitly specifying `.zip` extension in MSBuild Argument in the
  Build Definition.
  `p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)\package.zip`
- Check the build log, check if MSbuild works correctly. Also you can try the Msbuild command line locally to check if the .zip package can be generated.
- Deploy a new agent on your Develop machine, create a new build
  definition, then build with the new agent.

If still can not resolve the issue, just share the build logs here for further troubleshoot.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by explicitly specifying .zip extension when generating MSBuild Argument in the Build Definition. p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)\package.zip"